# Android display all characters in an ExpandableListView TypeFaces

Tags: android, special-characters, typeface

I'm creating an App which displays information from different sources - languages. Yet not all the languages use "standard" characters, like Thai, Khmer, Bengali, Hindi, Divehi.

While this is not a problem when a set of characters from a single source is displayed, since I could just load the appropriate TypeFace. But, I need a list of resources in each of these languages (including Western ones) in a single (clickable) list. Now some of the characters are replaced by boxed question marks.

So my question is, how can I load all the TypeFaces at once? 
Since the number of arguments for calling the setTypeFace is one (and recalling would override the previous one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is easier than I thought. Since each separate item in a ListView/ExpandableView can be regarded as TextField (or whatever). 
So in the Adapter where the values are set, add:

```
final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this, "fonts/some_font.ttf");
txtField.setTypeface(typeface);
txtField.setText(yourText);
```

Same as for 'normal' TextFields.